# Attribute limitation to the specific class

Tags: c#

I want to know if there is any way to limit usage of custom attribute to the specific class.
I read about it and somebody wrote that it's probably impossible in C#. But I have just tried to use *AttributeUsage* attribute on a class that doesn't derrive from *Attribute* and Visual Studio has thrown a following error:

> Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute

So now I think that there is a pretty smart way to make it. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Do you want violations of your rule that the attribute is only used on certain classes to show up at compile time? If you're willing to accept that the violation is first detected and noted at runtime you can do that with reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is by making the attribute class an inner class of the target. I have a hard time coming up with a legitimate reason to use this though.

This will compile:

```
[InnerAttribute]
public class A 
{
    private class InnerAttribute : Attribute
    {

    }
}
```

But adding this won't:

```
[InnerAttribute]
public class B
{

}
```

Comment: It's a good idea but I'm looking for more compact solution if it's possible as well.

Comment: Wow... I was in "not possible at compile time" camp... @vdrake6 what do you mean "more compact"?